# Do something when form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

how do I check if a form is closed?

I want to reload a listview's items when I close another form.
What I'm doing is:

Form1 = form with ListView
Form2 = form with TextBoxes

- Opening a new form.
- Creating a new folder via a textbox.
- When I press "Add" in Form2 I want to reload the "ListView" on Form1.

So how am I supposed to do this?

And sorry for my bad English :(.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes, I want to reload the listview in Form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is to make a public method on Form1, let's call it `RefreshList()` and in your button click event on Form2, you simply call `Form1.RefreshList`.  Here's a quick sample:

Form 2:

```
public Form1 ParentForm { get; set; }

private void Button_Click(object Sender, EventArgs args) {
{
    // After the rest of your handler
    if(ParentForm != null)
        ParentForm.RefreshList();

    Close(); // Close Form2 here, we're done!
}
```

Form 1:

```
private void ShowForm2() 
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ParentForm = this;
    form2.Show();
}

public void RefreshList() 
{
   // do your refresh here
}
```

Initially you mention that you want to do this when Form2 closes, but then later you mention that you want to do it "When I press "Add" in Form2 I want to reload the "ListView" on Form1."  As others have mentioned, you can use the `Closed` event, so I took this approach to address your second case.

Comment: Wow, your example looks nice! Yea, I know, my question is a little bit choopy :(, but I meant that when I press the "Add" button, the button executes some code and then closes the form.

Comment: @Darkshadw Tweaked the example a bit to close the form for ya. =)

Comment: This will work but it's not terribly well encapsulated.  For instance, if you wanted to reuse Form2 from a different parent form, it wouldn't work without further modification because it assumes it's parent form is always Form1.

Comment: @SteveDog I see, alright, I am going to give this a try though, thanks!

Comment: @SteveDog Yes, this wasn't meant to be a super-engineered solution, it was just trying to give him a starting point.  But your points are all valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the form [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event as the Closed Event is obsolete if you are using anything above dot net 1.1

Comment: The Closed event is obsolete and should not be used unless you're still using .NET 1.0. It actually says as much in the hyperlink you provided.

Answer (score 1):

In Form1, you can subscribe to From2's [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `FormClosed` event if you simply want to react to when a particular form is closed.  If you want to take it a step further, there is a `FormClosing` event that you could also handle and even prevent the form from closing if need to.

Answer (score 0):

Having Form1 add an event handler to Form2's `FormClosing` event is an excellent option.  However, there is an even simpler solution if Form2 is a dialog window.  In other words, if it's OK for Form1 to be effectively locked and disabled while Form2 is displayed, you can simply show Form2 as a dialog window.  Dialog windows show synchronously, so you can simply update the list immediately after showing Form2 and it won't hit that list-updating code until after Form2 is closed.  For instance:

```
form2.ShowDialog(this);
updateList();
```